# cannot pass(send) phoneno in curl instead of hardcoded phone no

Tags: php, curl

```
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "http://boancomm.net/boansms/boansmsinterface.aspx?mobileno=9448******&smsmsg=".$_REQUEST['MESSAGE']."&uname=username&pwd=password&pid=123");

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);

// grab URL and pass it to the browser
curl_exec($ch);

// close cURL resource, and free up system resources
curl_close($ch);

$xyz=mysql_query("select phone from students where student_id='$student_id'");
$xyz2=mysql_fetch_row($xyz);
$phoneno=$xyz2[0];
$sql = "INSERT INTO sms_fees (STUDENT_ID,SCHOOL_ID,MESSAGE,assigned_date,phonenumber)
                    values('".$student_id."','".UserSchool()."','".str_replace("\'","''",$_REQUEST['MESSAGE'])."','".DBDate()."','".$phoneno."')";
```

Comment: What is the problem ? I only see code. Add some text

Comment: Of course you can't. You're getting the `$phoneno` after the curl request. Move the curl part after the mysql select...

Comment: Yes...Thanks a lot Alex,now it is working fine....

Answer (score 0):

First try the URL in your browser with actual values, before using curl.

Answer (score 0):

The `$phoneno` is not available because it is not yet created.
Simply moving the `curl` part after the `mysql` solves the issue:

```
$xyz=mysql_query("select phone from students where student_id='$student_id'");
$xyz2=mysql_fetch_row($xyz);
$phoneno=$xyz2[0];
$sql = "INSERT INTO sms_fees (STUDENT_ID,SCHOOL_ID,MESSAGE,assigned_date,phonenumber)
values
('".$student_id."', '".UserSchool()."', '".str_replace("\'", "''",$_REQUEST['MESSAGE'])."', '".DBDate()."', '".$phoneno."')";


$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "http://boancomm.net/boansms/boansmsinterface.aspx?mobileno=".$phoneno."&smsmsg=".$_REQUEST['MESSAGE']."&uname=username&pwd=password&pid=123");

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
// grab URL and pass it to the browser
curl_exec($ch);
// close cURL resource, and free up system resources
curl_close($ch);
```

Also I suggest you migrate this to `PDO` or `mysqli`, since mysql_* has been deprecated.

Here are some helpful tutorials:

http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_ref_mysqli.asp

http://www.phpro.org/tutorials/Introduction-to-PHP-PDO.html